# Is Avg Monthly Searches = Avg Monthly Users in adwords keyword tool

Tags: keywords, google-ads

Hi While doing keyword research for my website [TFTH](https://www.thanksforthehelp.com/), I encountered with an confusion and need your solution.

In adwords keywords tool, for every keyword we get Avg Search Volume. My query is can we take it as Avg Users?

For ex I am targeting [Assignment Help](https://www.thanksforthehelp.com/au/) keyword and for this I get 12100 avg search queries. So is it ok to say 12100 users are searching for this keyword in a month?

Kindly confirm.

Answer (score 2):

Average Monthly Searches: The average number of times people have searched for the exact keyword based on the location and Search Network targeting that you've selected. By default, the number of searches for the term over a 12-month period are taken out as an average.

So this is number of times people have searched for a keyword vs how many people visited your site.